# Scala - Explicitly stating the short circuiting in defining && and || functions

Tags: scala, short-circuiting

In Scala source code for Boolean ([here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/Boolean.scala)), it is said that the functions && and || can not be defined using the => syntax.

```
// Compiler won't build with these seemingly more accurate signatures
// def ||(x: => Boolean): Boolean
// def &&(x: => Boolean): Boolean
```

But I can't see any problem with those definitions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source code said it won't rather than can't, maybe you have wrongly interpreted it.

If you see line 56 of Boolean.scala, you will find some explaination for ||.

> This method uses 'short-circuit' evaluation and
>   behaves as if it was declared as `def ||(x: => Boolean): Boolean`.
>   If `a` evaluates to `true`, `true` is returned without evaluating `b`.

same for && in the source code.
To sum up, it can define like that but there is no need to because of short-circuiting.

Comment: Thank you, I actually thought it is saying that it is not possible to define it that way.

Answer (score 4):

These definitions are perfectly fine, from a language user point of view.

They are however difficult to deal with internally by the compiler. A by-name parameter is transformed into an anonymous function class extending `scala.Function0[Boolean]`, which basically means that the condition

```
left() || right()
```

would be transformed to

```
left() || (new Function0[Boolean] {
  def apply(): Boolean = right()
})
```

Now, when emitting bytecode, the compiler would have a hard time emitting back something sensible with the efficiency intended by `left() || right()`.

So, because this is a primitive operation in the language, working with the primitive type `Boolean`, the compiler allows itself to *cheat*, and ask that `right()` not be a by-name. It thus sees the original code, and can easily transform it to something like

```
if (left()) true else right()
```

which is the same thing as

```
left() || right()
```

So, basically, this is an implementation detail/shortcut.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. So basically its some kind of short-circuiting that can only be used by the compiler programmer!